# MessageListener didnt receive full message ASMACK Android

Tags: android, asmack, message-listener

i got problem when want to receive message, right now i am able to receive message, but some attribut is missing

```
    class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        Util.DebugLog("message->"+message.toXmlns());

    }

}
```

what i got is

```
  <message to="2@buzoo.biz" type="chat" from="1@buzoo.biz/ff3b2485"><body asdf="asdf">aaa</body></message>
```

talk_id and chat type inside message is missing.

This is want i want when receive message

```
  <message to="2@buzoo.biz" type="chat" talk_id="304" chat_type="0" from="1@buzoo.biz/ff3b2485"><body asdf="asdf">aaa</body></message>
```

Answer (score 0):

While XMPP does not strictly forbid extending a stanzas by adding custom attributes to pre-defined elements (`message` in your case), it's the best to add the custom data as extra element. This is how most XMPP extensions are designed.

So instead of

```
<message to="foo@bar.com" type="chat" myCustomData="myValue"><body>Hello!</body><message>
```

you have

```
<message to="foo@bar.com" type="chat"><body>Hello!</body><myExtension myCustomData="myValue"/></message>
```

Then you simply need to write a Provider for `myExtension` and register it with Smack's `ProviderManager`.

Comment: but ios and web can receive that message without missing some attribute . so what have to do?im really stuck about it

Comment: Put your custom data within a element under `<message/>` and you will be able to retrieve the data.